# one checkbox to show/hide many HTML password input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have seen the example on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_password.asp) that shows how to toggle the visibility on a text/password input.

I would like to have something very similar but it would be one checkbox that can toggle several text inputs that are added in dynamically.

Something like the following:

*Note that the code below isn't going to work. It is here to give an example of my situation. I am wondering how to adapt the code seen on the link so I have used the same names as the example on w3schools*

**HTML**

```
<div class="container_home">

  <form id="inputFrm_h" class="inputFrm_home" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="env_name[]" /> = 
    <input type="password" name="env_contents[]" id="myInput"/>
    <button class="add_form_field_home">Add</button>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var wrapper_home         = $(".container_home");
  var add_button_home      = $(".add_form_field_home");
  var y = 1;

   $(add_button_home).click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     console.log('we here');
     y++;
     $('.inputFrm_home').append('<div><input type="text" name="env_name[]"/>  =
      <input type="password" name="env_contents[]" class="myInput"/>
      <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a><br></div>'); //add input box
    });

   $(wrapper_home).on("click",".delete", function(e){
     e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); y--;
    })

  });
```

Comment: Offtopic. When defining your element like `var add_button_home      = $(".add_form_field_home");`, then you can use that variable further on. So change `$(add_button_home).click(` to `add_button_home.click(`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an array to store these input elements and when you click the add button it will create and add the new input on the page and in the array. Then when you click the checkbox it will execute a for loop, which will then run through your array and change the type from password to text (making it the letters visible).

http://jsbin.com/risayiquha/edit?html,js,output

> HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="inputs">

  </div>
  <button onclick="createInput();">Add Input</button>
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="changeValues(this);">
</body>
</html>
```

> JavaScript

```
var inputList = [];

function createInput() {
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.setAttribute('type', 'password');
  document.getElementById('inputs').appendChild(input);
  inputList.push(input);
}
// This will essentially just create an input in whatever container you specify and also push the DOM element into an array. 

function changeValues(checkbox) {
  if (checkbox.checked) {
    for (var i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
      inputList[i].type = 'text';
    }
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
      inputList[i].type = 'password';
    }
  }
}
// This just changes the type from text to password for every element
// in the array based on if the checkbox is checked or not.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using jQuery, so you can [use that to select elements](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/) you want to work with, whether it's one or many.

In your case, `$('.inputFrm_home div')` will select all `div` elements that have been appended within the `.inputFrm_home` element. Which means `$('.inputFrm_home div').remove()` will remove all matching elements.

Add your Remove All link to the html:

```
<div class="container_home">

  <form id="inputFrm_h" class="inputFrm_home" method="post">
    ...
  </form>

  <a href="#" class="remove-new-fields">Remove new fields</a>
</div>
```

Then a click handler for the new link:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  ...
  $('.container_home').on('click', '.remove-new-fields', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.inputFrm_home div').remove();
  });
});
```

Or if you want to use a checkbox to toggle the new fields instead of the link, you can use something like

```
$('.my-toggle-checkbox').on('change', function (e) {
  if($(this).prop('checked')) {
    // checkbox is checked
  }
  else {
    // checkbox is not checked
  }
})
```